# Need to find specific nodes from xml document in jquery based on their attribute

Tags: jquery, xml

I have this xml document.

```
<search-results>
    <physician>
        <name>some name</name>
        <address>
            <street>some street</street>
            <city>some city</city>
            <state>some state</state>
            <zip-code>some zip</zip-code>
        </address>
        <phone>some phone</phone>
        <url>some url</url>
        <logos>
            <logo type="1">logo1</logo>
            <logo type="2">logo2</logo>
        </logos>
    </physician>
</search-results>
```

I am able to list physicians that have a logo of type 1 using this code.

```
$(results).find('physician').each(function () {

          var $physician = $(this);
          var logos = $physician.children('logos');
          var logo = logos.children('logo');

          if (logo.attr('type') == "1")
          {

              var html = '<h3>' + $physician.children('name').text() + '</h3>';
              html += '<p>' + $physician.children('logos').children('logo').text() + '</p>';
              html += '<p>' + logo.attr('type') + '</p>';


              $('#results').append(html);
          }

      });
```

However, not all physicians have both logos.

I need to be able to list physicians that have a logo with an id of 1, physicians that have an id of 2 and then physicians that have both logos.  I am having trouble finding the physicians that have both logos 1 and 2.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specifically need to find and output physicians in the particular order you give (logo 1, log 2, then both), then your best bet is to pre-compute lists of each type of physician and then iterate over them in the order you need.

You could, for example, do something like this:

```
var physicians = $(results).find('physician');

var logo1 = physicians.filter(function ( ) {
    return $('logo[type="1"]', this).length > 0;
});
var logo2 = physicians.filter(function ( ) {
    return $('logo[type="2"]', this).length > 0;
});

var physiciansWithLogo1 = logo1.not(logo2);
var physiciansWithLogo2 = logo2.not(logo1);
var physiciansWithBothLogos = logo1.filter(logo2);
```

The first two filter expressions use [filter functions](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#using-filter-function) to select those physicians which have a logo of `type="1"` and `type="2"` respectively (whether they have both kinds or not).

The next two lines use the [not filter](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to select physicians with only one or the other type of logo. These are put into the `physiciansWithLogo1` and  `physiciansWithLogo2` variables, which are jQuery objects containing the physicians which have only `logos` with `type="1"` and `type="2"` respectively.

The final line uses [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-jQuery-object) again to find the physicians containing both kinds of logo, which are put into a jQuery object `physiciansWithBothLogos`.

Once you've got those three objects, you can iterate over them (using [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), for example) and build your output as needed.